# Error & warning message box overlapping in question's title

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, error-message

This is a minor design problem -- the error and warning message boxes are   overlapping-

[image]

### Edit

As per the comments, **@Antoine Pelletier** asked, he can't reproduce this bug. So I just giving the details of how to reproduce this bug.

### Scenario:

- Go and click ask question button
- Fill question body first instead of filling question title
- Put your tag
- Then just type `fsdsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf dfsdf()` in title
- and click the `post your question` Button
- you should get an error message like this

[image: hh]

- Then remove the title and just type this `how to abc/abd dd()`
- then click the `post your question` Button

  > **Now you can should be getting the message box overlapping bug** like this

[image]

### Suggestion to fix

> It may related with z-index or position issue. But the simple conceptual solution  is **We should hide/remove the previous message/warning if you want to show a new warning/message**.

Comment: *What?! Don't you have superman's X-ray vision?*

Comment: Btw, there's a z-index issue as well. Even if displaying two messages at once were *okay*, the error should appear on top of the warning.

Comment: Kindly let me know this is a bug? Because I want to know this question is correctly asked and tagged? **Because am learning `how to ask a question` in meta stack overflow**

Comment: @RameshRajendran: Up-votes/down-votes to this question should tell you that.

Comment: @NisargShah `Even if displaying two messages at once were` Why we need to show two messages at a time? We should show only the primary message and should hide  non-primary message.

Comment: I can't even reproduce the problem, seriously, not a chance. How the hell did you got that, and what was the red error message (behind the yellow one) indicating ?

Comment: This is not a design issue. The error message should be reset if you re-perform the action that caused the popup in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this is no longer an issue since we switched to inline error messages:

> [image]