# Warning message appears twice in question's title

Tags: bug, asking-questions, error-message

After seeing [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360488/error-warning-message-box-overlapping-in-questions-title?cb=1) this morning, I decided to try it out as I'd never seen the warning message before. I typed in the same question title, and noticed that the warning message is actually added twice.

It appears the first time when you are manually typing out the title, and then a second time when the title box loses focus. If you try and close the warning without losing focus on the title, it disappears but then reappears again a second later as the similar questions list re-populates.

Can it be changed so that if the source already contains the warning it won't be added again, and if it is manually closed, it won't be shown again?

[image: question]

[image: markup]

Comment: Hopefully this will be broken several ways in weeks to come, tells us that they are finally doing something about the Ask Question page.  Yay.

Comment: @HansPassant I've never been more pleased to see things breaking, than I am seeing things go wrong with the Ask Question page!