# Warning tooltip overlaps the header

Tags: bug, user-interface, error-message

1. Write some invalid title into the title field.
2. Scroll down a bit.

Result:

[image]

The header should have highest z-index than that message-box.

Comment: Related: [Error & warning message box overlapping in question's title](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360488)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360537/warning-message-appears-twice-in-questions-title?noredirect=1&lq=1